# Help sorting nodes inside a list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Im currently working with a generic linked list in C# and I need to sort the nodes inside the list.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

// T is the type of data stored in a particular instance of GenericList.
public class GenericList<T>
{
    private class Node
    {
        // Each node has a reference to the next node in the list.
        public Node Next;
        // Each node holds a value of type T.
        public T Data;
    }

    // The list is initially empty.
    private Node head = null;

    // Add a node at the beginning of the list with t as its data value.
    public void AddNode(T t)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.Next = head;
        newNode.Data = t;
        head = newNode;
    }

    // The following method returns the data value stored in the last node in
    // the list. If the list is empty, the default value for type T is
    // returned.
    public T GetFirstAdded()
    {
        // The value of temp is returned as the value of the method. 
        // The following declaration initializes temp to the appropriate 
        // default value for type T. The default value is returned if the 
        // list is empty.
        T temp = default(T);

        Node current = head;
        while (current != null)
        {
            temp = current.Data;
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Where are the methods to remove a node and compare data in a node?  Those would be useful to have as well.

Comment: Will this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768095/sorting-a-linked-list

Answer (score 1):

I'd slightly change the list in this way:

```
// implement IEnumerable<T>
public class GenericList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    #region Constructors

    public GenericList()
    {
    }

    public GenericList(IEnumerable<T> values)
        : this()
    {
        foreach (var val in values)
            this.AddNode(val);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable Implementations

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator(this);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Nested Enumerator

    class Enumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private GenericList<T> innerList;
        private Node current;
        private bool started;

        public Enumerator(GenericList<T> list)
        {
            this.innerList = list;
            this.current = null;
            started = false;
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (!started)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't ask Current before calling MoveNext()");
                return current.Data;
            }
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return this.Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (!started)
            {
                current = innerList.head;
                started = true;
            }
            else
            {
                current = current.Next;
            }
            if (current != null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            started = false;
            current = null;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Your methods i.e. AddNode() etc.

    //...

    #endregion

}
```

Implementing `IEnumerable<T>` you can use LINQ `OrderBy()` and `OrderByDescending()` methods on the list (as well as iterate it using `foreach`), and the new constructor allows you to create a new linked list easier:

```
var sortedList = new GenericList<int>(unsortedList.OrderBy(x => x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're trying to ask:

"I don't know anything about the class of objects my list holds! How can I ever sort a list of objects I know nothing about?!"

Here's the answer to that question.

Your T type should implement an [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) is likely the one you want. This will give you a means of comparing the object that's passed in by requiring them to have a comparison method. Something like:

```
public class GenericList<T> where T : System.IComparable<T>
```

What this does is ensure that whatever generic class you make this List for, that class will have a CompareTo method, allowing objects of that class to be compared to other objects of that class. Comparison is a fundamental necessity of sorting.

Once you have that hooked up, you can sort your list using your favorite sorting algorithm, and using the CompareTo(T item) method. Simple algorithms would include [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). The ambitious might try out [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

If this isn't what you meant to ask, please let me know, and we can get to the bottom of what you're having trouble with.